# IDEA with openjdk9 produces 'cannot resolve symbol' error

Tags: intellij-idea, java, java-9

I'm using openjdk9 on Ubuntu:

```
openjdk version "9-Ubuntu"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b134-2ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b134-2ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

And it's obviously that there are no longer CLASS_PATH, tools.jar and rt.jar in JDK9, so I'm facing the problem that how to import these classes into my project.

```
public class FoolsDay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ahh, don't know how to use jdk9!");
    }
}
```

Even the simplest code won't run, for that there are no such class called `System` and `String`.

**However, the IDE still built the codes without any errors, but it failed to run because the 'cannot resolve symbol' issue makes it impossible to find the main method in this class.**

**But when I compile and run the code in terminal using `javac` and `java`, it works all fine.**

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: @JBNizet 2017.1

Comment: I just downloaded jdk9, added the new JDK in IntelliJ and created a new project, and it compiles and runs fine. But the latest version is build 9-ea+163. Maybe yours is really too old. I also don't understand how you can have a compilation error (cannot resolve symbol) when running code.

Comment: @JBNizet It's weird, I'm not sure whether there is a difference between openjdk-9 and oraclejdk-9, my code can be built with IDEA with no error, but it just cannot resolve symbols when I'm wirting.

Comment: b134 is a 7 month old (!) version of a in-development branch of openjdk 9. There have been a ton of changes to OpenJDK 9 in that time. Can you try with a slightly newer version? Like b160 or later?

Comment: @omajid OK, I've got the same advice from the JetBrains support, I'll update my jdk to check out whether the issue still exists.

Comment: I have this problem too...

Comment: @RayanFar openjdk-9 is currently version 9~b161-1 for ubuntu, you can also try http://jdk.java.net/9/ for early access build.